# SQL: Renaming All Variables at Once

Tags: sql, rename

My data looks like this:

```
        var1      var2     var3
1  0.8879615  9.145530  9.76198
2  8.3522106  8.921711  5.55693
3 16.1873228  6.099095 29.92102
4  5.1786637 15.209045  6.06162
5  3.8149316 15.078099 18.95941
6 -5.8267485  9.371876 23.20190
```

**Problem:** I want to rename all variables in this table by adding "_a" to the end of their names, so that it looks something like this:

```
      var1_a    var2_a   var3_a
1  0.8879615  9.145530  9.76198
2  8.3522106  8.921711  5.55693
3 16.1873228  6.099095 29.92102
4  5.1786637 15.209045  6.06162
5  3.8149316 15.078099 18.95941
6 -5.8267485  9.371876 23.20190
```

Normally, this can be done by individually renaming each variable. For example:

```
Create table new_table as select var1 as var1_a, var2 as var2_a, var3 as var3_a from original_table;
```

**My Question:** Suppose my table has 100 variables - I do not want to have to rename all these variables manually. **Is there a way to rename all these variables at once?**

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : Thank you for your reply! This is the first time I have heard of "dynamic sql" - is this difficult to do? Thanks!

Comment: I mean to say that you would need to write some kind of SQL script which gets all column names, then builds a query with the columns renamed.

Comment: @  Tim Biegeleisen: Thank you for your reply! I will start researching this right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can prepare the rename commands dynamiclly in one-shot and execute them in one shot:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name ||' RENAME COLUMN ' || column_name ||' TO ' || column_name|| '_a;'  
from _V_SYS_COLUMNS
where table_name = 'yopurtablename'
and table_schema = 'yourtableschemaname'
```

Comment: A Nice piece of dynamic SQL :)